# Generic Include on ObjectQuery doesn't actually include anything

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-4, eager-loading

Today I tried to modify my existing generic GetAll method to work with eager includes.
I have Lazy loading enabled, but I want to do eager loading for some specific caching optimizations.

```
  public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(List<string> eagerIncludeList) where T : EntityObject, new()
    {
        var entitySet = String.Format("[{0}]", FetchEntitySetName<T>());
        ObjectQuery<T> q = this.db.CreateQuery<T>(entitySet);



        foreach (string x in eagerIncludeList) {
            q.Include(x);
        }
        return q;
    }
```

The above code doesn't work (not eager loaded at least) , calling it with e.g.

```
DB.GetAll<PageConfig>(new List<string>() {"Containers"})
```

does not load the related Containers for my PageConfigs,
**BUT**
When hard coding the include, it does work, so i'm sure the name "Containers" is correct

```
var example = db.PageConfigSet.Include("Containers").ToList();
```

this gives example.First().Containers.IsLoaded = true;

Any ideas on why the generic code that uses CreateQuery doesn't work, but the one that uses the hard coded ObjectSet does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q.Include(x)` returns a new `ObjectQuery<T>` that includes that table.

You aren't doing anything with the return value.

Comment: shoot me! I've been looking at this for 1 hour! so the Include actually doesn't modify the input... okay!